# Multi array iteration

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have a function which is:

```
public function getpopularAction()
{
    $businessReviewMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessReviewsMapper();
    $result = $businessReviewMapper->getTotalPopular();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
    {
        $rotd[$i] = $businessReviewMapper->getROTD($result[$i]['review_id']);     

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($rotd); $j++)
        {
            $rotd[$j]['u_img'] = $this->view->getLoginUserImage(
                $rotd[$j]['social_id'], $rotd[$j]['login_type'], null, null, large
            );
        }
     }

     print_r($rotd); 
     exit;
}
```

The result i get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [review_id] => 161
                    [review_desc] => tgi goooood....................
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [rating] => 3
                    [review_date] => 20121022203529
                    [name] => zlippr
                    [social_id] => 12345678
                    [login_type] => facebook
                    [user_unique_name] => zlippr
                    [city] => Kuala Lumpur
                    [business_name] => TGI Friday Kuala Lumpur
                )

            [u_img] => /public/images/image_not_found.png
        )
)
```

I do not know where problem is but the *u_img* is not fetched properly, not sure whether the array loop is execute properly.

Comment: Enable PHP error warnings and notices to the highest level. Track your PHP error logging (or output if you have enabled it) then. From the code it looks like you have an undefined index at read of `$rotd[$j]['social_id']` and `$rotd[$j]['login_type']`. Doing your own error checking inside the logic you have here, might be useful, too (*"image_not_found.png"* looks like an "error"-message)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the inner loop is for. If you are trying to retrieve the loginuserimage corresponding to each rotd, you need to do like :

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
    {
       $rotd[$i] = $businessReviewMapper->getROTD($result[$i]['review_id']);     

       $rotd[$i]['u_img'] = $this->view->getLoginUserImage(
            $rotd[$i]['social_id'],$rotd[$i]['login_type'],null,null,large);
    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant codes especially getLoginUserImage and getROTD. Does the getROTD function return the array with correct  values?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your ouput, your result are inside 2nd layer of array which means you should replace your variable inside `getLoginUserImage` from

```
$rotd[$i]['social_id'],$rotd[$i]['login_type']
```

to

```
$rotd[$i][0]['social_id'],$rotd[$i][0]['login_type']
```